# getting INT value from HTML form with bottlepy

Tags: python, forms, int, bottle, iterable

I have a very simple peice of code which im trying to make add 2 numbers. Im quite inexperienced with python so im having a bit of trouble. Im using the bottle framework for python.

```
from bottle import get, post, request, run, validate
@get('/login') # or @route('/login')
def login_form():
    return '''<form method="POST" action="/login">
<input name="number" type="number" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>'''
@post('/login') # or @route('/login', method='POST')
def login_submit():
    name = request.forms.get('number')
    intnumber = int(number)
    return(intnumber + intnumber)
```

The trouble im having is the value returned from the textbox is a string type. So i can concatonate the two strings just fine but cannot convert them to an int to add them. It gives me the error

```
TypeError("'int' object is not iterable",)
```

when it tries to convert intnumber = int(number).

Any help on how to resolve this and why this is happening would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
from bottle import get, post, request, run, validate

#bottle.debug(True)

@get('/login') # or @route('/login')
def login_form():
    return '''<form method="POST" action="/login">
<input name="number" type="number" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>'''

@post('/login') # or @route('/login', method='POST')
def login_submit():
    number = request.forms.get('number')
    intnumber = int(number)
    return str(intnumber + intnumber)

run(host='localhost', port=8080)
```

Comment: Better: `number = request.forms.get('number', type=int)` and then (as you say) `return str(number + number)`.